# How to load bootstrap 4.5 JS dependencies with webpack 4.44 ProvidePlugin / exports-loader

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, bootstrap-4

I am learning webpack. I am using jQuery with Bootstrap, and so want to export tooltips in my setup. I have enabled them in my plugins:

```
 entry: {base: './src/static/js/modules/pages/base.js'}

 plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
      Tooltip: 'exports-loader?Tooltip!bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip',
      Popover: 'exports-loader?Popover!bootstrap/js/dist/popover',
      Dropdown: 'exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown',
      Modal: 'exports-loader?Modal!bootstrap/js/dist/modal',
      Tab: 'exports-loader?Tab!bootstrap/js/dist/tab',
      Util: 'exports-loader?Util!bootstrap/js/dist/util',
    }),
```

However, when initialising tooltips in `base.js`, I get `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function`

```
$(() => {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

When I load these dependencies directly in `base.js`, it works fine:

```
import 'popper.js';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/popover';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/modal';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/tab';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/collapse';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/util';
```

This tells me I am not initialising them correctly when trying to use `exports-loader` in the plugin. Jquery however is loaded and works as expected.

Where am I going wrong?

I am using `Bootstrap 4.5.0`, `Webpack 4.44.0`, `exports-loader 1.1.0`.